# How to start xfce after installing it?

Tags: linux, xfce, android, desktop-environment, slackware

I've installed the latest version of Slackware on my Android tablet (Lenovo a5500-hv) and I've installed xfce too. But when I want to run it using the command `startxfce4`, it fails with this error:

```
/usr/bin/startxfce4: line 118: exec: xinit: not found
```

I don't know how can I solve that. I'm new on Linux.

So, please explain everything as clearly as possible and the code to solve my problem and run this desktop on startup. This is a screenshot of what I said:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you have X Server installed? Try running `startx` command to see if X Server is installed correctly.

Comment: X probably isn't installed. I don't use Slackware, but in Debian you should install the `xorg` package to install the full X Window System.

Answer (score 5):

Two commands required:

1. `xwmconfig` to select your window manager
2. `startx` to start x :)

Perform both of these commands as an ordinary user...