# How to run Xfce on fresh Kali instsallation

Tags: x11, xorg, kali-linux, xfce

I'm failing to get a new Kali linux OS, with a working Xfce windows manager. I'm able to make a bootable USB, then install Kali on my system.

I downloaded the [Kali Linux 64-Bit (Installer)](https://www.kali.org/downloads/) (Version: [2020.1](https://cdimage.kali.org/kali-2020.1/kali-linux-2020.1-installer-amd64.iso)).

I followed the "Single Boot Kali" [instructions here](https://www.kali.org/docs/base-images/kali-linux-hard-disk-install/).

But when first booting into the new system, trying to run `startxfce4` fails with the following error

```
startxfce4
/usr/bin/startxfce4: Starting X Server
/usr/bin/startxfce4: 122: exec: xinit: not found
```

I tried troubleshooting a few things, but no dice.

- I can't run `startx` doesn't yet exist in the new system. And I haven't created any X or Xfce config files. I'm just logging into a new system.
- This [StackExchange issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268493/how-to-start-xfce-after-installing-it) is exactly like mine. But `xwmconfig` isn't on my system either.

Comment: this may help ... https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me/5361#5361

Comment: The error states you’re missing `xinit`. Install it and try again.

Comment: @Peschke I did try that, but got the error `E: Unable to locate package xinit`. Apparently this is because I am using an end of life unsupported version of Debian (or Kali). So I can update possibly update `sources.list`. But there's no instruction on what values Kali uses.

Comment: You said you use version 2020.1, which looks like the latest to me. The package can sometimes be called xorg-xinit or similar. You’ll have to double check the way Kali or Debian names it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I sorted this one out.

Out of the box, Kali's `/etc/apt/sources.list` is empty. Kali has a list of [Network Repositories](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/). So I just added the `kali-rolling` repository, then installed `xinit` and `xorg`. From there, running `startxfce4` works.

```
# add this line at the bottom of /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib

sudo apt-get update &&
sudo apt-get install xinit xorg &&
startxfce4
```